# Laravel using WHERE orWHERE

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query as below. When i search using the query below, it fetches the products but it shows other products from other airlines even tho i have specified the airline id. When i take out the `orWhere("code","LIKE","%{$request->search}%")`, it works perfectly fine and it doesn't show the products of other airlines.

I know where the issue is but then i still need the search parameter to be either name or code. How do i fix this ?

```
 Product::with('airline')
            ->where('airline_id', $request->airline_id)
            ->select('id','name','code')
            ->where("name","LIKE","%{$request->search}%")
            ->orWhere("code","LIKE","%{$request->search}%")
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Read up on [logical grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping)

Comment: @M.Eriksson. Thank you, that's what i am looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current query will generate:

```
WHERE airline_id = ? AND name LIKE ? OR code LIKE ?
```

The `OR` will discount any other conditions unless you group them properly. You need to use [logical grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping) to solve that:

```
->select('id','name','code')
->where('airline_id', $request->airline_id)
->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where("name","LIKE","%{$request->search}%")
          ->orWhere("code","LIKE","%{$request->search}%");
})
```

This will generate:

```
WHERE airline_id = ? AND (name LIKE ? OR code LIKE ?)
```

Comment: Great. This works as expected. Thanks for the knowledge!